# Glpi automatic action

Tags: server

I have a problem with an automatic action in GLPI, since the "Queuedmail", which is the action that sends the mail in queue every 1 minute according to my configuration, is not working, I do not know what to do, the only way to make it work is by manually executing it.

The version I use of GLPI is 9.1.6

Answer (score 1):

This is very little information.
You need to check:

1. Quedmail Status: Is it set to Scheduled?
2. Quedmail Run mode:

   - If set to CLI you need to add a cron job (This is recommended). http://wiki.glpi-project.org/doku.php?id=en:config:crontab
   - Just for testing, change Run mode to GLPI. It would run based on anyones GLPi usage.

Regards,

Comment: The sample crontab in that wiki has /usr/bin/php5, but you probably need to use /usr/bin/php or /usr/bin/php7.2 if you're doing this in 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, no email where sent by the cronjob and the queue status was always "**running**".
Solved it by stopping the cronjob, executing the following query in database, then reenabling the cronjob.

```
update glpi_crontasks set state=1 where name='queuednotification' and state=2;
```